# PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refuse - docker-vompose.yml

Tags: intellij-idea, docker, docker-compose

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой: Есть Dockerfile и docker-compose.yml. Задача: написать скрипт, который бы билдил приложение и запихивал его в контейнер. И чтобы потом его можно было запустить в браузере.

**Dockerfile такой:**

```
`FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

WORKDIR root/

ADD ./backend/build/libs/backend-*.jar ./application.jar

EXPOSE 8080

RUN apk add --no-cache xvfb wkhtmltopdf --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/

CMD java -server \
    -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled \
    -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 \
    -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark \
    -jar /root/application.jar`
```

**docker-compose.yml :** есть 2 сервиса postgres и rabbitmq

```
    version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: post-service
    image: postgres:9-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/db_migration/cdp_dump.sql:/home/postgres/cdp_dump.sql

    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - 8080


  rabbitmq:
    container_name: rabb-service
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST}
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "15674:15674"
      - "5671-5672:5671-5672"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: test1
```

файлик docker-build2.sh : здесь надо написать логику.
Здесь в PERFORM BUILD SCRIPT создается файлик build_script - в нём 2 строки: cd /root и ./gradlew build -x test
Далее в CREATE SERVICES - создаются сервисы (postgres и rabbitmq) и запускаются (docker-compose up). В BUILD APPLICATION билдится приложение и потом в BUILD IMAGE собирается в контейнер с именем test на основании докерфайла .
Далее в RUN - я пытаюсь запустить контейнер, потом в браузере ввожу localhost:8080 но у меня ничего не происходит а в консоли в IDEA вылетает ошибка.
Ошибка снизу.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

# ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES

POSTGRES_HOST=localhost:5432
POSTGRES_DB=continuous_delivery
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgresPassword
RABBITMQ_HOST=localhost
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=admin
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=/

PROJECT_HOME=$(pwd)


# PERFORM CLEANING
cleanup() {
    docker stop post-service
    docker rm post-service

    docker stop rabb-service
    docker rm rabb-service
}
cleanup


# PERFORM BUILD SCRIPT
touch build_script
echo cd /root > build_script
echo ./gradlew build -x test >> build_script


# CREATE NETWORK FOR DOCKER-COMPOSE
docker network create test1


# CREATE SERVICES
export POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER} &&\
    export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD} &&\
    export POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB} &&\
    export RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER} &&\
    export RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS} &&\
    export RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST} &&\
    docker-compose up -d
    sleep 10s
    docker-compose exec -u postgres postgres psql -c "create database ${POSTGRES_DB};"
    docker-compose exec -u postgres postgres psql -c "create database jira_adapter;"
    docker-compose exec -u postgres postgres psql -c "create database cdp_mailer;"



# BUILD APPLICATION
docker run --rm --name build -i --net test1 \
                             -v ${PROJECT_HOME}:/root \
                             -e POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST} \
                             -e POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB} \
                             -e POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER} \
                             -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD} \
                             -e RABBITMQ_HOST=${RABBITMQ_HOST} \
                             -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER} \
                             -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS} \
                             openjdk:8-jdk /bin/bash < build_script


# BUILD IMAGE
docker build -t test .


# RUN CLEANING
#cleanup


# RUN
docker run --rm --name build -i --net test1 \
                             -e POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST} \
                             -e POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB} \
                             -e POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER} \
                             -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD} \
                             -e RABBITMQ_HOST=${RABBITMQ_HOST} \
                             -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER} \
                             -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS} \
                             -p 8080:8080 \
                             test
```

Ошибка: коннект к базе не теряется, обновить базу могу, IDEA видит её.

```
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:215) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:404) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:272) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar!/:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:50) [flyway-core-3.2.1.jar!/:na]

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:61) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:144) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
        ... 110 common frames omitted
```

Люди добрые, помогите, очень нужно. Я уже думал порты надо дописать в docker-compose.yml для сервиса postgresql, т.к. мне кажется один порт 5432 указан и он становится занят и поэтому получается такая вот ситуация. Пробовал добавить другие порты, безрезультатно. Может кто-нибудь знает выход из этой ситуации ? Буду очень благодарен! Спасибо !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен!
В енвайронмент переменных вместо POSTGRES_HOST=localhost:5432 указал имя сервиса из файла docker-compose.yml